# Can't get multiple buttons to simultaneously align horizontally and vertically

Tags: html, css

I've been attempting to get multiple buttons to align vertically and horizontally next to each other in the center of the page. This is what I am aiming for: [aligned buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQ76P.jpg)

However, I have only either gotten the images to center, but then they are not horizontally aligned. Or, I have gotten them to align horizontally, but they are not centered. Here is the code I am using on the buttons.

```js
//used to remove the transition item so that the image changes. This is necessary to show image transition on load. 
$(".hoverImage").removeClass("transitionHoverImage")

//sets welcome text opacity to 0 so it can be faded in
$('.welcomeText').css("opacity", 0);
//wait a second before attempting to fade text in. Second parameter of "fadeTo" sets opacity to 1 (100%)
$('.welcomeText').delay(1400).fadeTo(800, 1);

$('.portfolioBtn').css("opacity", 0);
$('.portfolioBtn').delay(1400).fadeTo(800, 1);

$('.resumeBtn').css("opacity", 0);
$('.resumeBtn').delay(1400).fadeTo(800, 1);
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Oswald, Baloo, Calibri, sans-serif;
    background: black url(../images/background.jpg) no-repeat center;
    height: 3600px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}


.about {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ffffff rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    position: relative;
    width: 904px;
    padding: 33px 27px 34px;    
    z-index: 1;
}
.logo {
    position: fixed;
    left: .25em;
    top: 3%;
    height: 210px;
    width: 150px;
    z-index: 1;
}

/* you want to set up a transform, translate for this transform: translate (0, -100px); and  */
.hoverImage {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.transitionHoverImage {
    transform: translate(0px, 200px);
}

.door {
    transition: transform 1.5s ease-out;
}

.welcomeText {
    position: relative;
    top: 120px;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 7em;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.centerBtns {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    top: -700px;
    text-align: center;   
    width: 15%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: black;
    background-color: #fdc552;
    border-radius: 1em;
    border-color: #805300;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px black;
    padding: 1.5em 2.8em;
    z-index: 2;
}

.resumeBtn {
   
}
.portfolioBtn {}

/* why is this so finnicky?!?!?!?!?!?!?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!???????????
/* dropdown menu code starts here */
/*this is the code for the revealed box and the dropshadow of box */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    right: 2em;
    top:3%;
    background-color:#343434;
    min-width: 1em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    box-shadow: .25em 0em .5em #343434;
    padding: 0em;
    z-index: 1;
}

/* this is the highlight color when you hover over an item */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: dimgray;
}

/*w3 said I needed this code, so I put it in */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content{
    display:block;
}

/*revealed dropdown style */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: lightgray;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #343434;
    background-color: #343434;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    padding: .5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
/*menu button for dropdown*/
.menu-button {
    position: fixed;
    right: 2em;
    top:3%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: lightgray;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: #343434;
    border-color: #343434;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- favicon links-->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">



<title>DenneyDesign</title>
<!-- CSS Stylesheets -->
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<ling href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo|Oswald" rel="stylesheet"> 

</head>

<body>
<!--Menu Bar-->
    <div class="dropdown">
         <button class="menu-button">MENU</button>
         <div class="dropdown-content">
             <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
             <a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
             <a href="#artwork">ARTWORK</a>
             <a href="#resume">RESUME</a>
             <a href="#social">SOCIAL</a>
</div>
    </div>
<!--Logo-->    
<div>
<img class ="logo" src="images/logo.png">
</div>

<!--Welcome Text-->
<div>
    <header>
    <h1 class='welcomeText'>WELCOME</h1>
</header>

<!--Hover Image-->
<img class="door hoverImage transitionHoverImage" src="images/door_slider.png">

</div>

<!--Buttons-->
<div>
    <button class="centerBtns"><b>PORTFOLIO</b></button><button class="centerBtns resumeBtn"><b>RESUME</b></button>
</div>

<!--About-->
<div>
    <header>
    <h1><a name="about">ABOUT</a></h1>
    </header>
</div>

</body>


<!--javascript-->
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Check out your opening and closing tags. You have an `<b>` tag that opens in your first `<button>`, and gets closed in your second `<button>`. Not sure if that's your problem, but that is why your *Run code snippet* result is broken here.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that! Didn't fix things sadly.

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox does this easily. Use `display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;` on the parent.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 50vh;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>button</button>
  <button>button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! 

Apparently something else is causing the issue then, because they are still placing the buttons on top of each other. I'll update the question with the rest of my code if you wouldn't mind helping some more!

Answer (score 0):

Using flexbox is indeed the simplest solution, but just in case I re-arranged your CSS:

```css
.centerBtns {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;   
    color: black;
    background-color: #fdc552;
    border-radius: 1em;
    border-color: #805300;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px black;
    z-index: 2;
    
    width: 40%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 1.5em;
    line-height: 3em;
    }
```

```html
<div>
    <button class="centerBtns"><b>PORTFOLIO</button><button class="centerBtns resumeBtn">RESUME</b></button>
</div>
```

If you want both buttons to have the same width make sure the width % is large enough to contain the text. Or if not just remove the width property and tweak around with the last 3 properties to get the results you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've updated my question to contain all of my code. The flexbox helped with the centering but the buttons were not placed side-by-side, sadly.

Comment: @AaronDenney If you want to have your buttons side by side try to add `display: inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with the code you've provided, and I believe that may be making it difficult to isolate the problem.

A stripped down version of what you posted shows how this can be achieved with a combination of relative positioning and [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).[image]

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: auto auto;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
 }

.nav {
  border: solid 1px blue;
  background: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  width: 750px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav__button {
 font-size: 44px;
 margin: 50px;
 width: 250px;
 padding: 30px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <button class="nav__button">Portfolio</button>
  <button class="nav__button">Resume</button>
</div>
```

Plunker mirror of the above here: http://plnkr.co/edit/LwJyRFFpSE9dj4KtCuw6

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply! I think it probably is confusing because I have both a nav bar, and then buttons on the page that do the same thing. However, they are two seperate things. I'll try translating the code you posted over to the buttons and see where that gets me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AaronDenney - What I meant was the code you've posted here doesn't run properly. There are javascript and other includes placed outside of your closing `<body>` and closing `<html>` tags. Not sure if it's that's the case in your actual setup, but that's the reason your code is broken in the code snippet section of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FlexBox. If you have a few buttons, you can set the "justify-content" property as "center", and set a margin to each button. On the other hand, if you have many buttons, you can set the "justify-content" as "space-around", and remove the margin.

https://jsfiddle.net/pablodarde/nhxukt5c/

**HTML**

```
<div class='buttons'>
    <button>
      <b>PORTFOLIO</b>
    </button>
    <button>
      <b>RESUME</b>
    </button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.buttons button {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 5px;
}
```